# Swift playground: get ViewController to call presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, uialertcontroller, swift-playground

I would like to play with UIAlertController in Playground. Is it possible to get the ViewController from XCPlaygroundPage - to be able to call presentViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly get a view controller, but because there's no "attached" view controller you'll end up seeing a warning that looks like this:

`Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`

And in my case, the alert controller flash on screen super briefly and then disappeared.  Perhaps you could improve upon this somewhat?

Anyways, here is how I created the view controllers in the playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 420)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView!
    let items = ["Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3"]
    var alertController : UIAlertController? {
        didSet {
            if alertController == nil {
                print("alertController set to nil")
            } else {
                print("alertController set to \(alertController)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view.frame)
        self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(self.items[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "My Title", message: "Testing in Playground", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
            // Some action here
            print("hit okay button")
        }

        alertController!.addAction(okAction)

        ctrl.presentViewController(alertController!, animated: false, completion: {
            print("done presenting")
        })
    }
}

var ctrl = ViewController()
var rootVC = RootViewController()
rootVC.addChildViewController(ctrl)
rootVC.view.addSubview(ctrl.view)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = rootVC.view
```

And what I'm doing here is I create a "root view controller", add a child view controller with a table (in an attempt to get some view controller "attached" to something else) and then I tried to present an alert controller on that.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the liveView to your Window *after* presenting, to avoid the warning.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let window = UIWindow()
let viewController = UIViewController()
window.rootViewController = viewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title here", message: "message here", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action here", style: .default, handler: nil))
viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = window
```

Result:
[image: UIAlertController on timeline]